# Font for Div tag not showing on Internet

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have the font showing locally, have uploaded the file to the website, and it still is not showing up on several browsers that I have tried.  I've tried many different ways in my stylesheet.css and the main.css, but nothing is working.

Can anyone help me to see where I am not getting something right?

It is only the "Sarah Brody" that I am looking to add a script font to.

Thanks in advance...  [sarahbrody.me](http://sarahbrody.me) is the website.

Sue

Comment: I get this error in the console when I go to your site: "http://sarahbrody.me/webfonts/Great_Vibes/stylesheet.css -  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)". I guess that has something to do with your problem.

Comment: Took out the link to the webfont...that was only when I was trying to link to it and then it wasn't working anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You must define your font in CSS. Something like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Aphrodite Stylistic";
  src: url('font/aphrodite-stylistic.eot');
  src: url('font/aphrodite-stylistic.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('font/aphrodite-stylistic.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('font/aphrodite-stylistic.woff') format('woff'),
       url('font/aphrodite-stylistic.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

I noticed that in main.css you are importing `webfonts/Great_Vibes/stylesheet.css` but that file is missing. That's probably causing the problem. Check it's URL.

Comment: What if I only want that font for that one div? 
And thanks, I kept getting the error locally about that webfont css file and couldn't figure it out...I didn't have it either!

And that webfont was where I was trying to use a google font and thought it would be easier..not!

Comment: I tried the @font-face...I've tried so many things...I can't remember where I put it..in the stylesheet.css or the main.css, but I may have tried both and nothing I had tried work.

Can you tell me where exactly to put it?  Which css gets it or both?  And then will it effect the other parts of the page?

Comment: Added it to the stylesheet.css and it's still not working... :(

Comment: If you want to use non-standard font on your site, you must add `@font-face` somewhere at the beginning of your css. It is important that you have that font on your server and url in `@font-face` must point to it. Copy/paste of my code won't help if you don't have those font files on server.

Comment: @S.Brody: Listen to cakan, the URL to the files are wrong... You have both the folder and the name of the files wrong in your CSS. Your font files are located in http://sarahbrody.me/fonts/ and you can see the name of the files there. Just correct it and it will work.

Comment: @cakan, where does this go?  stylesheet.css?  main.css?  html?

Comment: @kamelkent, how do I point to the folder called "fonts" correctly?  How do I fix this?  I can move the fonts to anywhere to make it work...just not sure where

Comment: @cakan, all my files for the aphrodite are the otf extension, is a problem too?

Comment: @cakan, I do see I have some up on the server with different extensions: i.e., eot, otf, svg, ttf, woff...I am really confused

Comment: Rename your font `Aphrodite Stylistic.otf` to `aphrodite-stylistic.otf` and keep it in fonts directory. Then add this to the beggining of your `stylesheet.css`: 
@font-face {
  font-family: "Aphrodite Stylistic";
  url('fonts/aphrodite-stylistic.otf') format('opentype');
  font-weight: normal;
}

Comment: @S.Brody Do just as cakan just wrote. I think maybe you need to read up on relative URLs: http://www.webreference.com/html/tutorial2/3.html

Comment: You have a typo in your css, font file extension is not oft, but otf.

Comment: @Cakan, you are the BEST!  Thanks..must need a cup of coffee!  Thanks so much!  I am not a coder but am enjoying trying!